# Two different Selects with the same option, then animate overflowed div or error message

Tags: jquery

EDIT: Oh well, now im managing to make it work properly. But I need the error message to .hide if the user select the proper option after having the error message.

Here is the html/jquery im working on

```
 <form>
 <select>
     <option>Please Select Your Value</option>
     <option>Pick this value 1</option>
 </select>
 <div class="error">Please select your value</div>

 <select>
     <option>Please Select Your Value</option>
     <option>Pick this value 2</option>
 </select>
     <div class="error">Please select your value</div>

     <input type="submit" value="Show Hidden Div" />         
 </form>

 <div class="suprise">
   Hidden Div
 </div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
   var correct = true;
   $('select').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() != 'option2value'){
       //next is the error... it might be better to use an id there
       $(this).next().show();
       correct = false;
     }
   })
   if(correct){
    $(".results").animate({ 
            marginTop: -480}, 400); 
   }
 })
```

I just need a little help around here, how to make the proper trigger... Im not sure how to do it thou.

Thanks guys!

Comment: The selector `$(".results")` will never select anything in the given HTML - there are no elements having a class of `results`.  Have you thought of using [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)? Even for seemingly simple validation like this it often makes sense to use a battle-hardened library.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to insert a id into `select`

```
<select id="select1">
     <option>Please Select Your Value</option>
     <option>Pick this value 1</option>
 </select>
 <div class="error">Please select your value</div>

 <select id="select2">
     <option>Please Select Your Value</option>
     <option>Pick this value 2</option>
 </select>
```

```
$("select[id^=select]").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "select1") {
        if ($(this).val() == $("#select2").val()) {
            alert("You are wrong");
        } else {
            alert("You are right");
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($(this).val() == $("#select1").val()) {
            alert("You are wrong");
        } else {
            alert("You are right");
        }
    }
})​
```

Comment: Use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")`, and `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @VisioN does it make any difference?

Comment: At least it is faster and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, sorry for it. I was having a trouble playing through the .next without setting the .error div... Its working right now, thanks for the help.